# How to apply filter on magento 2 collection like below query?

Tags: database, collection, filter

THis is my core Mysql query

> select * from `table_name` where CONCAT(',',
> subscriptions, ',') like '%,4793,%'

and i want to apply below filter on magento 2 collection.
where CONCAT(',', subscriptions, ',') like '%,4793,%'

Comment: I assume you have comma separated values stored in this field. You should try field in set

Answer (score 1):

Use `Zend_Db_Expr`

Example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where(new \Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(',', subscriptions, ',') LIKE (?)"), '%,4793,%');
```

Comment: No, I Have Data in table below format.

{"tracks":{"album":"Megamix Chart Hits 2022","title":"Do It Better","artist":"Felix Jaehn Feat. Zoe Wees","bpm":"133","year":"2022","duration":130,"filename":"34 - Felix Jaehn Feat. Zoe Wees - Do It Better.mp3","filepath":"\/manageplaylist\/4833\/41866\/Megamix Chart Hits 2022\/34 - Felix Jaehn Feat. Zoe Wees - Do It Better.mp3"}}

and i want collection where title equal to